# Can someone explain to me what each loop, and variable means in Bottom up Merge Sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I am having a rough time understanding the Pseudocode for the bottom up merge sort algorithm.

Conceptually, I sort of understand what's taking place.

1. we iterate through the array and separate each element into it's own array
2. we merge the first two adjacent arrays (containing 1 element each) to create a new sorted array of 2 elements.
3. we iterate through the array again, this time doubling the amount of elements placed into 
   a new array. These elements have already been sorted by the previous merge and iteration step.
4. we merge the first two adjacent arrays (this time containing 2 sorted elements each) to create a new sorted of array of 4 elements.
5. this process continues until the entire array is sorted.

I'm looking at the pseudocode from this site - http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort

```
Input: array a[] indexed from 0 to n-1.

m = 1
while m < n do
    i = 0
    while i < n-m do
        merge subarrays a[i..i+m-1] and a[i+m .. min(i+2*m-1,n-1)] in-place.
        i = i + 2 * m
    m = m * 2
```

But I am getting lost after the first while loop! The recursive implementation was more intuitive for me, but the iterative approach is throwing me off! If anyone can implement it in python or c++, and explain each step, and what each variable is for I would greatly appreciate it.

Cheers!

Comment: Watch [this gif](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Merge-sort-example-300px.gif). This is a visualization of what the code is doing.

Comment: I'd suggest trying it with a shuffled deck of index cards, each with one number written on it.  Follow the instructions by hand to see why the deck ends up sorted.

Comment: I'll give this a shot sometime for future sorting problems. I usually write on scratch paper to see what's happening, but the card suggestion sounds interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is the number of elements being sorted together. It starts with 1 element, and keeps doubling until we've merged one half of the list with the other half.

`n` is the size of the list.

`i` is the index of the first element of the first subarray being merged.

`i + m` is the first element of the second subarray being merged.

Here's a simple example.

```
Say I have the following n=5 list: a = [3,1,2,5,4]

m = 1:
    Merge each 1 element subarray with its 1 element neighbor subarray

    i = 0:
        Merge [3] and [1] -> [1,3]
        a is now [1,3,2,5,4]

    i = 2:
        Merge [2] and [5] -> [2,5]
        a is now [1,3,2,5,4]

m = 2:
    Merge each 2 element subarray with its 2 element neighbor subarray

    i = 0:
        Merge [1,3] and [2,5] -> [1,2,3,5]
        a is now [1,2,3,5,4]

m = 4:
    Merge each 4 element subarray with its 4 element neighbor subarray

    i = 0:
        Merge [1,2,3,5] and [4]
        a is now [1,2,3,4,5]. We're done sorting.
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks making it clearer. This was very helpful.